# prove that for the equivalence class : X/(X/E) = E

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let E be an equivalence relation on the set X .
prove that: X / (X / E) = E

The definition of euivalence class: x/E = { for every y in the X | xEy }

The set of all equivalence classes: X/E = { x/E | x is a member of X }

Comment: You defined x/E but did not define X/E.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Yes you are right. I have edited the information and appended the definition of X/E.

Comment: Ok.  So how is X/E, a collection of  subsets of X,  an equivalence relation.  X/E subset P(X).  Equivalence relations for X are subsets of X×X.